# Moving column filters to the top of the table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using the [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin for the first time (v1.9.4). I was following this example ([Individual Column Filtering](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)), but I want the filter dropdowns to appear under "Search all columns".

[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: I know I modified your question pretty heavily; please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Also, this is a guess (full disclosure), but in the `$(document).ready`, did you try changing the JQuery selector from "`tfoot th`" to "`thead th`"?

Comment: thanks for modification :) .. i tried, but not working

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try. I'll take a look at this in my spare time (I haven't used the column filtering like this before), and I'll try to answer you over the next day or so.

Comment: you will find the example on this path ((DataTables-1.9.4\examples\api)) the name of example is ((multi_filter_select.html))

Comment: and you can check this file ((DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js))

Comment: Drat. Changing to this...`$("thead th").each( function ( i ) { this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) ) + this.innerHTML;`...will preserve the table headers and move the select elements to the top, but clicking on them will also sort them.

Comment: what is (Drat.) ? .. where i will find it ?

Comment: Ah. Drat is a mild expression of annoyance; while the code I had above will technically wotk, it won't do it perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ChrisForrence .. Work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I recently had the same issue and didn't find exactly what I needed and hope that it is useful for others.  Here is how I resolved it:

In the `<thead>`element, create 2 `<tr>` elements, each with the appropriate # of `<th>` columns.  Add the column header names to the second `<tr>` element.  Apply the standard `class='select-filter'` attribute (in the second `<tr>`) to those headers that will require a select list. Add an `id` attribute in the following format: `*headerValue*-select-filter` (where *headerValue* = the name of the header, it MUST match exactly) wherever you would like to place the select list (could be in different column etc.). The appendTo function will take the header name and create the id to attach to.

Header HTML:

```
<table>
 ....
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div id="Column4-select-filter"></div></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="active">
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th class="select-filter">Column4</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 ....
</table>
```

The script portion will take the value of `<th>` from the th(s) with the select-filter attribute (In the example above = "Column4"), then it will generate the following tag `#Column4-select-filter`.  The script will then append the completed select list to the `<div>` with the corresponding `id`.  In the sample above, it would be the first column (you can place this in any column). You could also create a `<div>` anywhere in your layout and this will work.

JavaScript:

```
 table.columns('.select-filter').every(function (index) {
    var that = this;

    // Get the header name for this column
    var headerName = table.column(index).header().innerText;
    // generate the id name for the element to append to.
    var appendHere = '#' + headerName + '-select-filter';

    // Create the select list and search operation
    var select = $('<select />')
        .appendTo(
        $(appendHere)
        )
        .on('change', function () {
          // DO STUFF HERE
        });

    // CAN HAVE OTHER TASKS HERE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will preserve the table headers, as well as move the `<select>` elements to the top. The only caveat? Clicking on them will also sort them. If you can live with this, however, then you can follow the [given example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html), making the following modification to the document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Initialise the DataTable */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        }
    });

    /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table header */
    $("thead th").each(function (i) { 
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i)) + this.innerHTML;
        $('select', this).change(function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To prevent the column filter from inadvertently firing the column sorting (when a user chooses a column filter) simply add: `event.stopPropagation();` after the `oTable.fnFilter();`

Comment: This answer isn't even close to what the author of the question asked for. Could you explain what this has to do with an alternative position of the dropdown filters?